# A question about poles of function

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

Consider the function $f(z)=\dfrac{\sin \frac{\pi z}{2}}{\sin (\pi z)}$.

Then $f$ has pole at

1) all integers

2) all even integers

3) all odd integers

4) all integers of the form $4k+1$, $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

My idea: given function  $f(z)=\dfrac{\sin \frac{\pi z}{2}}{\sin (\pi z)}$

so for poles $\sin (\pi z)=0 \rightarrow \pi z=n\pi \rightarrow n=z $ hence $1$ is right?

Comment: specify your $p$ is it an interger or not

Comment: Sine is zero for any integer multiple of $\pi$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $f(z)$ be given by

$$f(z)=\frac{\sin(\pi z/2)}{\sin(\pi z)}$$

Note that $f$ has removable singularities when $\pi z/2=n\pi$ for $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ since

$$\lim_{z\to 2n }\frac{\sin(\pi z/2)}{\sin(\pi z)}=(-1)^n\frac12$$

With those singularities removed, $f$ is a meromorphic function with simple poles at $z=(2n-1)$, $n\in \mathbb{Z}$.

So, the answer is $3)$.

Comment: ...is that option (4) also right?

Comment: Well, certainly $4k+1$ is an odd integer, but does not include all odd integers.

Answer (score 1):

The only point you are missing is this:

Out of $z=n\pi$, $n\in\mathbb Z$; the even multiples of $\pi$ are flushing the numerator also to zero.

Also  $Lim_{z\rightarrow 2k\pi} f(z)= \frac{(-1)^k}{2}$ (by LH rule); thereby indicating that these are removable singularities rather.

And the denominator $g(z)=sin\pi z$ has a simple zero at $z=(2k+1)\pi$ as $g'((2k+1)\pi)=cos((2k+1)\pi)\ne 0$, so $f(z)$ has simple zeroes here.

Correct options are $3,4$.